# Strange behaviour of network speeds during Linux upgrades?

Tags: networking, ethernet, arch-linux, wget, package-management

I am on Manjaro Linux and today when I was upgrading my system I saw a very strange behaviour of my ethernet network speed.
But first let me tell you that my ethernet download speed is capped at 300 KiloBytes per Second.

The line I have highlighted is my normal download speed and the line below is the strange download speed.

Why does it happens???? Also when I asked it in my distro's forum, a maintainer asked me to test if such behaviour is shown by wget while download large files like ISO and it didn't.

Here are the pictures: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpTTb.png] [image: https://forum.manjaro.org/uploads/default/original/2X/2/24e34d75f7d9f09e10ed0cabe01e3285b87958d5.png]

Comment: Could the abnormally fast packages be ones you already have downloaded or cached?

Comment: No. The upgrade was done on a freshly installed system. I installed it about a hour ago

Comment: Was the install media still mounted and available? It could have been "downloaded" from that...

Comment: Alternatively perhaps your ethernet passes through some kind of caching proxy. Your speeds to the internet could be capped, but speeds from the proxy are at full ethernet speed.

Comment: Yeah but thats a case but consider there is hardly any Linux User in my area. But that my approximation.

Comment: Also I don't have any Proxy setting in my eternet profile but I am behind a NAT as my ISP NATs all the users.

Answer (score 1):

The only people who can answer this definitively will be your ISP - My (very educated) guess is that there is a mirror which you are connecting to which is not bring rate limited - possibly because its on their LAN before the rate limiter or becausevthey have createdcan exception -its not uncommon for ISPs to exclude content available to them cheaply from caps.

In order to check this hypothesus, monitor the download speed (for example using iptraf or equivalent)

Comment: Download speed of what? Packages or other downloads?